# Is line 4 inside the if statement started on line 2?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, chaining

I'm trying to learn about chaining and how to do it myself by reading OPC.  I'm still very stuck.  While learning this, I ran into a bit of error handling that raised my eyebrows.  It seems, from the indentation, that line 4 is not a part of the if statement that begins on line 2.  Am I right to assume that 2-line if statements do not require curly braces, and the interpreter assumes that when there is a lack of curly braces, only the line directly proceeding an if statement is a part of that same if statement; therefore, the fourth line is not a part of the if statement in the following block:

```
    set: function (mystr, func) {
        if (!this[mystr])
            throw new Error("unknown hook " + mystr);
        this[mystr] = func;
    },
```

Comment: This is not the best example for your question - because the throwing of the Error would mean that line 4 wouldn't be executed even if it *was* within the `if` block.  (Which it isn't.)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Kills two birds with one stone.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's typically not the *line* but the *statement* succeeding the if-statement that's considered belonging with it.

Comment: Thank you.  So basically everything prior to the next semicolon.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08. Semicolons are optional in JS. Without braces, it's the next **ON* STATEMENT**.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be **[ONE STATEMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp)**.

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces are only required if you have multiple statements inside the block. If you don't use braces, the next statement (single) will be inside the block, the following statements will be outside the block.

```
if (something)
    StatementIfTrue();
StatementEitherWay();

if (something)
{
    StatementIfTrue1();
    StatementIfTrue2();
}
StatementEitherWay();

if (something) StatementIfTrue(); StatementEitherWay();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Mad respect for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, line 4 is not in the if block.

Without the braces, only the next statement right after `if` will be in the if block.